# Проблема с Quickly в Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, pygtk

Установил из репозитория пакет для быстрой разработки приложений на Python - Quickly, обнаружил, что команды quickly edit, quickly design и run отсутствуют.

```
~/Workspace$ quickly edit
ERROR: No edit command found.
Candidate commands are: commands, getstarted, help, quickly
```

хотя в списке допустимых команд они присутствуют

```
[ubuntu-application]    add
[ubuntu-application]    configure
[ubuntu-application]    create
[ubuntu-application]    debug
[ubuntu-application]    design
[ubuntu-application]    edit
[ubuntu-application]    license
[ubuntu-application]    package
[ubuntu-application]    release
[ubuntu-application]    run
[ubuntu-application]    save
[ubuntu-application]    share
[ubuntu-application]    submitubuntu
[ubuntu-application]    test
[ubuntu-application]    tutorial
[ubuntu-application]    upgrade
[builtins]  commands
[builtins]  getstarted
[builtins]  help
[builtins]  quickly
[ubuntu-flash-game] configure
[ubuntu-flash-game] create
[ubuntu-flash-game] debug
[ubuntu-flash-game] edit
[ubuntu-flash-game] license
[ubuntu-flash-game] package
[ubuntu-flash-game] release
[ubuntu-flash-game] run
[ubuntu-flash-game] save
[ubuntu-flash-game] share
[ubuntu-cli]    configure
[ubuntu-cli]    create
[ubuntu-cli]    debug
[ubuntu-cli]    edit
[ubuntu-cli]    license
[ubuntu-cli]    package
[ubuntu-cli]    release
[ubuntu-cli]    run
[ubuntu-cli]    save
[ubuntu-cli]    share
[ubuntu-cli]    test
[ubuntu-cli]    upgrade
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Это проблема с Ubuntu 12.10 или Quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос можно закрыть, дело в команде перехода в каталог с проектом. Я набирал

```
cd ./test
```

а нужно

```
cd test
```